# ¿Por qué decimos "despedirse a la francesa"?

Tags: expresiones, historia, españa

En muchas ocasiones habremos usado la expresión "se ha despedido a la francesa" cuando una persona se marcha de una reunión sin despedirse ni decir nada, sin avisar. Esta expresión está recogida en el DLE:

> **[a la francesa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IO0xZ7t)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. Al uso de Francia.
> 2. loc. adv. Repentinamente, sin decir una palabra de despedida. *Se despidió a la francesa. Me marché a la francesa.*

La inclusión por parte de la RAE de esta expresión en el diccionario fue en 1925:

> **A la francesa.** m. adv. [...] **2.** Con los verbos *despedirse, marcharse, irse*, significa bruscamente, sin decir una palabra de despedida.

Aunque en otros diccionarios aparece mucho antes, como en el *Domínguez* y el *Gaspar y Roig*, ambos de 1853:

> A LA FRANCESA : al uso o estilo de los Franceses, como se acostumbra en Francia. —Por estension descortesmente, sin despedirse de nadie.

¿Por qué usamos esta expresión? ¿Qué tienen que ver los franceses con irse sin decir nada? ¿Desde cuándo se recoge su uso?

> *—Don Federico, el vino empieza a explicarse. Son las doce de la noche, los chiquillos están solos en casa con Momo y fray Gabriel y me temo que Manuel empine el codo más de lo regular. El tío Pedro se ha dormido en un rincón y no creo que sería malo tocar la retirada. Los burros están aparejados. ¿Quiere usted que nos despidamos a la francesa?*
>
> Fernán Caballero (Cecilia Böhl de Faber), "La gaviota", 1849 (España).

Comment: ¿Esta expresión se usa en alguna región en especial? Nunca antes la había oído.

Comment: @DGaleano pues no sabría decirte. Los ejemplos que aparecen en el CORDE y en el CREA son en su mayoría de España, aunque aparece también en textos de Perú y Cuba. Seguramente fuera de España tenga un uso minoritario, así que le he puesto la etiqueta regional apropiada.

Answer (score 4):

Todas las fuentes que he encontrado coinciden en el relato: se trata de una forma de irse de las fiestas que se popularizó entre la burguesía francesa durante el siglo XVIII.

Me gusta especialmente cómo lo explican en [*Esta es otra historia*](https://estaesotrahistoria.wordpress.com/tag/sans-adieu/):

> En una de estas oleadas de innovación en la corte francesa del siglo XVIII se tomó la moda de marcharse de las fiestas y eventos sin despedirse. Esta nueva práctica era conocida como Sans adieu ( sin adiós).
>
> Se convirtió en algo habitual en las clases más altas de la sociedad como la burguesía o la nobleza. Por diferenciarse del pueblo todo valía. En este caso, los más humildes sí continuaban despidiéndose los unos de los otros allí dónde iban o venían.
>
> La moda de no despedirse se defendía aludiendo a que se consideraba una falta de educación interrumpir una charla en cualquier evento únicamente para informar de su marcha. Era más respetuoso de cara a los demás irse sin más anuncio, desaparecer.
>
> Tanto era así que incluso el gesto de mirar el reloj estaba un poco mal visto, aunque era lo único permitido como manera sutil de anunciar que no tardarían en irse de la fiesta.
>
> Se tenía también la opinión de que el hecho de no decir adiós era señal de deseo de volver o de haber disfrutado del acto en cuestión.
>
> Como podréis imaginar no tardó demasiado en pasar de moda y regresar a la normalidad de decir un adiós, hasta luego o gracias al marcharse de un lugar.

Otras fuentes:

- [¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión ‘Despedirse a la francesa’?](http://%C2%BFCu%C3%A1l%20es%20el%20origen%20de%20la%20expresi%C3%B3n%20%E2%80%98Despedirse%20a%20la%20francesa%E2%80%99?) de Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe
- [Despedirme a la francesa](https://fragmentosnomadas.blogspot.com/2012/02/despedirme-la-francesa.html?view=flipcard), en un blog
- [Despedirse a la francesa](https://elpais.com/diario/2007/12/30/catalunya/1198980441_850215.html), artículo de Enrique Vila-Matas (que vivió en París muchos años).

Curiosamente, en francés a la expresión le llaman [*filer à l'anglaise*](https://www.thelocal.fr/20190821/expression-of-the-day-filer-a-langlaise) (*some reports date the origin of French leave back to the 1850s and closely tie the expression to the Napoleonic campaign and the cowardice of French soldiers*). Debatieron un poco del tema en French.SE: [“French leave” in French](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/30257/10449).